# Scraping tables using beautiful soup but not displaying as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have been trying to scrape a table using a mixture of guides and chatgpt.

I have been bringing in the following html code:

```
<tr>


<td class="number">

<a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101">33101</a>

</td>
<td><a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101">SK19 EOM</a></td>

<td class="last-seen">
500
</td>
<td class="last-seen">

7 Jan 23:30

</td>
<td>ADL Enviro400 City</td>
<td class="livery-cell">

<div class="livery livery-962"></div>
Glasgow Airport Express

</td>




<td class="trivia"></td>
<td class="trivia">USB power</td>

<td><a href="https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=SK19EOM%20or%20%22SK19%20EOM%22%20or%20First%2033101&amp;sort=date-taken-desc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Flickr</a></td>

<td><a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101/edit">Edit</a></td>

</tr>
<tr>


<td class="number">

<a href="/vehicles/fgla-33102">33102</a>

</td>
<td><a href="/vehicles/fgla-33102">SK19 EOO</a></td>

<td class="last-seen">
500
</td>
<td class="last-seen">

7 Jan 18:35

</td>
<td>ADL Enviro400 City</td>
<td class="livery-cell">

<div class="livery livery-962"></div>
Glasgow Airport Express

</td>




<td class="trivia"></td>
<td class="trivia">USB power</td>

<td><a href="https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=SK19EOO%20or%20%22SK19%20EOO%22%20or%20First%2033102&amp;sort=date-taken-desc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Flickr</a></td>

<td><a href="/vehicles/fgla-33102/edit">Edit</a></td>

</tr>
```

Following these guides what i've tried is

```
# Parse the HTML of the web page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find all the buses on the page
buses = soup.find_all('table', class_='fleet compact')

print(buses)

# Loop through the buses and extract the information
for bus in buses:
  fleet_number = (bus.find('td', class_='number').text)
  registration = (bus.find('td', class_='number'))
  service_number = (bus.find('td', class_='last-seen').text)
  last_seen = (bus.find('td', class_='last-seen'))
  model = (bus.find('td').text)
  

  # Print the scraped information
  print(fleet_number)
  print(registration)
  print(service_number)
  print(last_seen)
  print(model)
```

But this only gives me

```
33101

<td class="number">
<a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101">33101</a>
</td>

500

<td class="last-seen">
500
</td>

33101
```

But my expected output was

```
33101 
SK19 EOM 
500 
7 Jan 23:30 
ADL Enviro400 City
```

I'm unsure how to do it any other way currently. Would there be a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<tr>
  <td class="number">
    <a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101">33101</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101">SK19 EOM</a>
  </td>
  <td class="last-seen"> 500 </td>
  <td class="last-seen"> 7 Jan 23:30 </td>
  <td>ADL Enviro400 City</td>
  <td class="livery-cell">
    <div class="livery livery-962"></div> Glasgow Airport Express
  </td>
  <td class="trivia"></td>
  <td class="trivia">USB power</td>
  <td>
    <a href="https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=SK19EOM%20or%20%22SK19%20EOM%22%20or%20First%2033101&amp;sort=date-taken-desc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Flickr</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="/vehicles/fgla-33101/edit">Edit</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="number">
    <a href="/vehicles/fgla-33102">33102</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="/vehicles/fgla-33102">SK19 EOO</a>
  </td>
  <td class="last-seen"> 500 </td>
  <td class="last-seen"> 7 Jan 18:35 </td>
  <td>ADL Enviro400 City</td>
  <td class="livery-cell">
    <div class="livery livery-962"></div> Glasgow Airport Express
  </td>
  <td class="trivia"></td>
  <td class="trivia">USB power</td>
  <td>
    <a href="https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=SK19EOO%20or%20%22SK19%20EOO%22%20or%20First%2033102&amp;sort=date-taken-desc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Flickr</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="/vehicles/fgla-33102/edit">Edit</a>
  </td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for row in soup.select("tr"):
    tds = [td.text.strip() for td in row.select("td")]
    fleet_number, registration, service_number, last_seen, model = tds[:5]
    print(fleet_number, registration, service_number, last_seen, model, sep="\n")
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
33101
SK19 EOM
500
7 Jan 23:30
ADL Enviro400 City
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
33102
SK19 EOO
500
7 Jan 18:35
ADL Enviro400 City
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```